# Regex.Replace punctuation signs

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following input string

```
some text ) more text
some text , more text
some text ! more text
some text ; more text
some text ? more text
some text . more text
some text)more text
some text,more text
some text!more text
some text;more text
some text?more text
some text.more text
some text )more text
some text ,more text
some text !more text
some text ;more text
some text ?more text
some text .more text
```

I'm using the Regex.Replace method hoping to get

```
some text) more text
some text, more text
some text! more text
some text; more text
some text? more text
some text. more text
some text) more text
some text, more text
some text! more text
some text; more text
some text? more text
some text. more text
some text) more text
some text, more text
some text! more text
some text; more text
some text? more text
some text. more text
```

But my string remains unchanged.

This is my class:

```
public class PunctionationSignsSpaceing : ILanguageRuleFormater
    {
        private string _pattern;
        public PunctionationSignsSpaceing()
        {
            _pattern ="( *[),!;?.] *)";
        }
        public string FormatString(string str)
        {
            str = Regex.Replace(
                str,_pattern,"$1",
                RegexOptions.Multiline|RegexOptions.Compiled
            );
            return str;
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here? (I'm a bit new to regex.) 
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the examples but I still don't understand your problem. Please could you also explain what you want to do in prose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is invalid. You're replacing whole match with itself, and that's why you don't see any change in your result string.

Try that one:

```
public class PunctionationSignsSpaceing
{
    private string _pattern;
    public PunctionationSignsSpaceing()
    {
        _pattern = " *([),!;?.]) *";
    }
    public string FormatString(string str)
    {
        str = Regex.Replace(
            str, _pattern, "$1 ",
            RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled
        );
        return str;
    }
}
```

You should also consider moving `_pattern` initialization from object constructor into field itself:

```
public class PunctionationSignsSpaceing
{
    private string _pattern = " *([),!;?.]) *";

    public string FormatString(string str)
    {
        str = Regex.Replace(
            str, _pattern, "$1 ",
            RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled
        );
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `\s` instead of a space. It looks clearer what is happening.

Comment: @Sukima Isn't \s whitespace (not just the space character) from what i know there are more characters that display whitespaces and i just want the space character

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using regex

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    char[] punctiationMarks = new char[]{'.', ',', '?', '!', ';', ')'};
    string inputString = "foo; bar;foo ,  bar , foo\nbar, foo ) bar foo  )bar";
    StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder ();
    int indexOfPunctuationMark = -1;
    inputString
        .Split (punctiationMarks, StringSplitOptions.None)
        .ToList ()
            .ForEach (part => {
                indexOfPunctuationMark += part.Length + 1;
                outputString.Append (part.Trim ());
                if (indexOfPunctuationMark < inputString.Length)
                    outputString.Append (inputString [indexOfPunctuationMark]).Append (" ");
            }
    );

    Console.WriteLine (outputString);
}
```